# Bad Request Почта России

Tags: php, rest

ссылка: https://otpravka-api.pochta.ru/1.0/user/backlog

Хедеры:

```
    $headers[] = "Authorization: AccessToken ".$this->token_app;
    $headers[] = "X-User-Authorization: Basic ".$this->key_auot;
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    $headers[] = "Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8";
```

Ошибка:
stdClass Object

```
(
    [timestamp] => 2019-03-07T14:36:18+0300
    [status] => 400
    [error] => Bad Request
    [message] => Bad Request
    [path] => /1.0/user/backlog
)
```

Comment: И что дальше???

Comment: Предоставьте больше информации: какой метод используете, какие данные помимо заголовков отправляете (желательно полный трейс запроса и ответа)

Comment: Метод создания заказа https://otpravka.pochta.ru/specification#/orders-creating_order . Я ничего не отправляю, так как что с отправкой данных что без не работает

Comment: данные вам по-любому придется передавать. `Bad Request` как раз может быть из-за отсутствия данных.

Comment: запрос каким образом отправляете? через curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Подготовка данных для передачи. Метод создания заказов принимает
   массив данных по заказу, каждый элемент которого представляет из
   себя примерно такой массив:

   ```
   $orderData = [
       'address-type-to' => DEFAULT,
       'comment' => 'Комментарий',
       'fragile' => false,
       'house-to' => '15 к 1',
       'index-to' => 195279,
       'insr-value' => 244000,
       'mail-category' => WITH_DECLARED_VALUE_AND_CASH_ON_DELIVERY,
       'mail-direct' => 643,
       'mail-type' => POSTAL_PARCEL,
       'manual-address-input' => false,
       'mass' => 291,
       'order-num' => 1546545,
       'payment' => 244000,
       'payment-method' => CASHLESS,
       'place-to' => 'г Санкт-Петербург',
       'recipient-name' => 'Иванов Иван Иванович',
       'region-to' => 'г Санкт-Петербург',
       'room-to' => 10,
       'sms-notice-recipient' => 0,
       'street-to' => 'ул Ленина',
       'tel-address' => 79210000000,
       'no-return' => true,
   ];
   ```
2. Отправка данных. Данные для создания заказов передаются методом PUT
   в формате JSON. Для передачи используем curl:

   ```
   $url = 'https://otpravka-api.pochta.ru/1.0/user/backlog';   
   $method = 'PUT';
   $headers = [
       'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
       'Authorization: AccessToken ' . $this->token_app,
       'X-User-Authorization: Basic ' . $this->key_auot,
   ];
   $data = json_encode([$orderData]);

   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   $response =  curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   ```
3. После отправки запроса в ответ в случае успешной обработки должно
   прийти примерно следующее:

   ```
   {
       "result-ids" : [ 57565818 ]     
   }
   ```